# Can you POST a form to a struts Action, from an external site?

Tags: struts

I am working with a third-party site which POSTs a response to a URL that I specify. When debugging the Action class which handles this path, I see that the request parameters are blank after the redirect.

My provided url is of the form http://example.com/Registration.do

This is my struts-config.xml entry.

```
<action path="/Registration" type="com.example.RegistrationAction">
    <forward name="success" path="/registration/success.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

Is there a way to submit a form from an external site, so that the request parameters will be passed correctly?

Comment: Request parameters *should* be blank after a redirect--a redirect is a new request. A post is a post, it doesn't matter where it comes from. Note that this forward isn't a redirect, though.

Comment: The only way if you leave an external site.